# Table of Contents in Landscape mode with Clickable local links

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to create table of contents page for my PDF in Landscape mode and the links are not working as they do in Portrait mode.

Here's the sample code:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
PffWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
doc.open();

// Create a chunk and add it to the document.
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Click this link to goto second page.");
chunk.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);
chunk.setLocalGoto("test");
chunk.setLocalDestination("test1");
doc.add(chunk);

// Skip rest of current page and begin a new page.
doc.add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);

// Create a chunk and add it to the document.
chunk = new Chunk("Click this link to goto first page.");
chunk.setUnderline(0.2f, -2f);
chunk.setLocalGoto("test1");
chunk.setLocalDestination("test");
doc.add(chunk);
doc.close();
```

Instead of:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
```

if i do:

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
```

it works as expected and the links work very well. But it fails in the landscape mode.